# Pandas calculating month difference vector

Tags: python, pandas, date-difference

I want to compute a **month difference vector** to my given df based on the following rules :

```
Date1       Date2      
12/31/2017  1/1/2018    
12/31/2017  2/1/2018       
12/31/2017  1/15/2018
```

The logic is as the following:

column d1:  (Date1+ 1 month) - Date2

column d2:  (Date1+ 2 month) - Date2

column d3:  (Date1+ 3 month) - Date2 and so on...

The output would be:

```
Date1       Date2       d1    d2   d3  ... d10
12/31/2017  1/1/2018    0     1    2   ... 9
12/31/2017  2/1/2018    -1    0    1   ... 8
12/31/2017  1/15/2018   0     1    2   ... 9
```

What would be best approach for this without manually defying each d1, d2, d3, ...d10 each time?

Many thanks!

Comment: How are you rounding? I ask because in the first row of your sample output for `d1`, you have a result of `0`... if your resolution was days and not months it would be 30 days... basically a month. So what are your rounding rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need ?(PS: You can change 4 to 10 will give back what you need)

```
#df.Date1=pd.to_datetime(df.Date1)
#df.Date2=pd.to_datetime(df.Date2)

d=dict(zip(np.arange(1,4).astype(str),((df.Date1.dt.to_period('M')-df.Date2.dt.to_period('M')).values[:,None]+np.arange(1,4)).T.tolist()))
df=df.assign(**d)
df
Out[1231]: 
       Date1      Date2  1  2  3
0 2017-12-31 2018-01-01  0  1  2
1 2017-12-31 2018-02-01 -1  0  1
2 2017-12-31 2018-01-15  0  1  2
```

I will recommend `concat`

```
v=pd.DataFrame((df.Date1.dt.to_period('M')-df.Date2.dt.to_period('M')).values[:,None]+np.arange(1,4),columns=np.arange(1,4).astype(str)).add_prefix('d')

pd.concat([df,v],1)
Out[1238]: 
       Date1      Date2  d1 d2 d3
0 2017-12-31 2018-01-01   0  1  2
1 2017-12-31 2018-02-01  -1  0  1
2 2017-12-31 2018-01-15   0  1  2
```

Comment: any reason for downvote ? You do not need cancel the downvote, if you have a reason and improvement come with that will be helpful

Comment: I don't see any reason why anyone would downvote this :)

Comment: @TylerNG that is fine:-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer given in days, since you don't specify how you'd like to round your months.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
for i in range(1,11):
    df["d{}".format(i)] = (df['Date1'].apply(lambda x: x + relativedelta(months=+i)) - df['Date2'])
```

this gives you:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! the answer looks like it was generated by Tableau.  How did you do that?

Comment: That is just a screen grab from my Jupyter Notebook.